# Setinterval Changing the color of a cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to change the color of the two cells in a html table after every 250ms.

http://jsfiddle.net/m4n07/DYP69/

If i uncomment the second block of setInterval code , the color changing stops even for the first one.

I would like to change the color in both the cell 1 and 2 , at the same time. Thanks

Comment: Please put code **in the question itself**, don't just link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same flag, which leads to some sort of lock probably. The easiest solution for you is to just add another flag for the second version - but wouldn't it be much nicer with just one interval-function? If I were you I would probably also want to cache the elements instead of doing a lookup at each interval.

*Update;*

From a (removed) comment, you wanted to add elements dynamically to the same interval-function? I wrote a small plugin for you (yeah, slow and boring day at work). You can add elements and change CSS class names at runtime, or even stop the interval. Only tested in FireFox though, but it's standard JS and should work in most browsers...

**JavaScript file**

```
(function (window, document, undef) {

    var CB = {};

    if (typeof window.CB !== typeof undef) {
        return;
    }

    CB = function () {

        var elements   = [],
            classes    = ['first-round', 'second-round'],
            intervalId = 0;


        var flag     = 0;
        var switcher = function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].className = classes[flag];
            }

            flag = 1 - flag;

        };


        return {

            setClasses: function (first, second) {

                classes = [first, second];

            },

            addElement: function (element) {

                elements.push(element);

            },

            init: function (element, firstClass, secondClass) {

                this.addElement(element);
                this.setClasses(firstClass, secondClass);

                return this;

            },

            start: function (interval) {

                intervalId = setInterval(switcher, interval);

            },

            stop: function () {

                clearInterval(intervalId);

            }

        }

    }();

    window.CB = CB;

})(window, document);
```

**HTML test page with usage example**

The test adds two additional elements at runtime (a timeout on 5 seconds), and changes the classes as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <style>

            .container {
                width: 600px;
                margin: 50px auto;
            }
                .container > div {
                    width: 300px;
                    height: 50px;
                    float: left;
                }
                .container .clear {
                    clear: both;
                    float: none;
                    width: 0;
                    height: 0;
                }

            .first-class {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .second-class {
                background-color: blue;
            }

            .new-first-class {
                background-color: black;
            }
            .new-second-class {
                background-color: grey;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="Id1">

            </div>

            <div id="Id2">

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="Id3">

            </div>
            <div id="Id4">

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="CB.js"></script>
        <script>

            window.onload = function () {

                CB.init(document.getElementById('Id1'), 'first-class', 'second-class');
                CB.addElement(document.getElementById('Id2'));

                CB.start(120);

                setTimeout(function () {

                    CB.addElement(document.getElementById('Id3'));
                    CB.addElement(document.getElementById('Id4'));
                    CB.setClasses('new-first-class', 'new-second-class');

                }, 5000);

            };

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

From a slight change to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/DYP69/6/

Since you said you want them to change colours simultaneously, you can use just one interval:

```
var flag = true;

setInterval(
    function(){
        if (flag) {
            document.getElementById("Id1").style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById("Id2").style.background = "blue";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("Id1").style.background = "blue";
            document.getElementById("Id2").style.background = "red";
        }
    flag = !flag;
    }, 250);​
```

Edit: tidied up code.

Comment: Please put code **in the answer itself**, don't just link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question *(not my dv, btw)*

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
var flag = true;

setInterval(
function changeColor () {
    if(flag==true){
        document.getElementById("Id1").style.background="red";
        document.getElementById("Id2").style.background="red";
        flag=false;
    }
    else if (flag==false){
    document.getElementById("Id1").style.background="blue";
    document.getElementById("Id2").style.background="blue";
    flag = true;
    }
}, 110);
```

Comment: Please put code **in the answer itself**, don't just link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question *(not my dv, btw)*